# php sequency through array with if-loop

Tags: php, sequence

I have the following array:

```
$moods = array("neutral", "happy", "sad");
$newarray= "";
```

I want to use an if-loop that goes through the array $mood in sequence and gives a different output based on what $moods value is selected

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 7; $x++) {

[insert code for sequencing through $moods here]

if ($moods == "neutral") {
    $output1 = "1";
    $newarray.= $output1
}
else {
    $output2 = "0";
    $newarray.= $output2
}
```

with the desired output being that $newarray is filled with $output1 and $output2 values such that

```
$newarray= "1001001";
```

I have tried using array_rand:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 7; $x++) {

    $mood= array_rand($moods,1);

    if ($mood == "neutral") {
        $output1 = "1";
        $newarray .= $output1
    }
    else {
        $output2 = "0";
        $newarray.= $output2
    }
```

but the problem with this is that it selects a random variable from the $moods array, instead of going through it in sequence.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you want your output to be kind of a binary string (`"100"` if neutral, `"010"` if happy`)? But you don't seem to have a value in your code to which to compare to. It also seems unclear why you would want this output

Comment: Not exactly, I want the output to be a string of "100" if $moods is "neutral" [1] "happy" [0], "sad" [0]. If $moods was ("neutral", "neutral", "happy") I would want and output of "110". I have edited the original post for clarity (more than 3 iterations)

Comment: So you want every 3rd value to be picked as `neutral`?

Comment: If you simply want a binary string, then just create one. What is the point of $moods etc?

Comment: Yes, I want every 3rd value to be picked as neutral, as well as every 3rd value (starting from 2nd iteration) to be picked as happy, and every third to be picked as sad.

Comment: @Icewaffle Then how does the accepted answer do any good, with respect to what you mean when you say _as well as every 3rd value (starting from 2nd iteration) to be picked as happy, and every third to be picked as sad._ ? Are there going to be 3 different binary strings, like `1001001`, `0101010` and `001001001`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$moods = ['neutral', 'happy', 'sad'];
$newarray= '';

foreach($moods as $mood) {
   $newarray .= $mood == 'neutral' ? '1' : '0';
}
```

### Update based on updated question

```
$moods = ['neutral', 'happy', 'sad'];
$newarray= '';

// initail index should be 0 to access correct value in $moods
for($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
   $newarray .= $moods[$i % (count($moods))] == 'neutral' ? '1' : '0';
}
```

Comment: How would you modify this for more than 3 iterations?

Comment: with the updated answer I seem to be getting a syntax error that I cannot identify: syntax error, unexpected token ")", expecting ";"

Comment: it was a typo and fixed.

Comment: thanks, but this is giving the unexpected output of "1010101" instead of the desired 1001001 - also, could you explain what is happening in the process $moods[$i % (count($moods) - 1)] ? I don't really understand what this string of code is doing - in particular the "$i % (count)" part of the code.

Comment: I fixed the code. `$i % (count($moods)` calculates modulo to get index. When $i is 1 and count is 3, it returns 1. When $i is 5 and count is 3, it  returns 2. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to an element of the array using the subscript (`[]`) operator:

```php
for ($x = 1; $x <= 3; $x++) {
    $mood = $moods[i];
    if ($mood == "neutral") { # Note that this should relate to $mood, not $moods
        $output1 = "1";
        $newarray.= $output1;
    } else {
        $output2 = "0";
        $newarray.= $output2;
    }
}
```